# Time complexity of for loop where i starts with a variable (not 1 or 0)

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, time-complexity

I want to know the time complexity of a for loop for(i=m;i<=n;i++) where m and n are both variables. I am thinking it will be O(n-m) as the loop is dependent on both values of m and n. 
Please guide me !

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation

Assuming your loop only executes statements that run in constant time, i.e. `O(1)`, you simply have to count the amount of loop iterations.

Your loop head

```
 for (i = m; i <= n; i++)
```

will generate iterations with `i` being `m`, `m + 1`, `m + 2`, `m + 3`, ... , `n - 2`, `n - 1`, `n`. So from `m` to `n`, both ends inclusive.

So exactly `n - m + 1` iterations (simple example `2`, `3`, `4`, `5` with `5 - 2 + 1 = 4`).

Thus, the asymptotic time complexity is

```
O(n - m + 1) = O(n - m)
```

Like you said.

Comment: O(m+n), O(m-n), O(max(m, n)), O(min(m, n)) are not all identical, although O(m+n) and O(max(m, n)) are. For example, m+n is not O(m-n). Because that would mean there's a M and C such that for all m, n such that max(m, n)>M, then m+n <= C|m-n|. But when m and n are large and equal, this inequality is always false. Definition from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiple_variables

Comment: Nicely and clean explained!

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed, it is `O(n-m+1)` since it will start at `m` and reaches `n` in the worst-case scenario.

Comment: Note that `O(n-m+1)` equals `O(n-m)`, the `+1` has no effect whatsoever on the asymptotic complexity.

Comment: Yes, of course, you are right, I just put it for the sake of explaining the exact scenario.

Comment: Yes thank you. if within the for loop, there is a statement like sum=sum+A[i] //sum initialised to zero in the beginning, then the whole loop will still have a complexity of O(n-m) right?

Comment: Yes, this is the worst-time complexity to be particular.